# iOS in-App browser

Tags: ios, swift, inappbrowser, rss-reader

Hey so I am building an iOS RSS Reader News app. Some long RSS articles end with a  "Read more" link. After clicking "Read more", Safari opens up. I want it to - instead of having Safari open that link - open it inside the app.

Note: I need this to function permamently with every link in the app and without me having to manually change what links will be opened inside the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a WebViewController, just a regular ViewController with a webView with the size of the screen. So then you just

```
        let webViewController = WebViewController()
        webViewController.title = yourRSSItem.title
        webViewController.request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: yourRSSItem.url)!)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewController, animated: true) //you can present it as well
```

Comment: And for iOS 9+, check out [Safari View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=504)